# How to fix read property 'showimagepicker' of undefined React-Native with Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a project where I need to upload or capture an Image to the server, so I installed the package ImagePicker into the project but when I try to use the property showimagepicker i get error "cannot read property 'showimagepicker' of undefined"

i try the changed The versions but doesn´t work. I currently have are:

-Android Studio Virtual Device i create a phone with Android 8.0

-"expo": "^ 32.0.0",

-"react": "16.5.0",

-"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",

-"react-native-image-picker": "^ 0.26.7" BTW "^ 0.24.0".

I try modify android-settings.gradle:

include ':react-native-image-picker'
project(':react-native-image-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProje 
ct.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android')

and in AndoidManifest.xml i put:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response)  => {

```
   if (response.didCancel) {
      console.log('User cancelled photo picker');

   }
    else if (response.error) {
      console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
    }
    else {
          console.log('imagen', response)
         let source = { uri: response.uri, uriOri:response.origURL, data: 
         response.data };

         let item = {
            data:response.data,
            test:'test123',
            source: source
          }

         var {cantImg} = this.state
         if(this.state.avatarSource1 == null){
            this.setState({avatarSource1: source})
            cantImg++
            console.log(cantImg)
          }else if(this.state.avatarSource2 == null)
          {
            this.setState({ avatarSource2: source })
            cantImg++
            console.log(cantImg)
           }else if(this.state.avatarSource3 == null)
          {
            this.setState({ avatarSource3: source })
            cantImg++
            console.log(cantImg)
          }
      this.setState({ cantImg: cantImg })
      this.refs.x.focus()
      const dismissKeyboard = require('dismissKeyboard');
      dismissKeyboard();
      Keyboard.dismiss()

   }

 });
```

I currently receive the error "Cannot read property 'showimagepicker' of undefined"

Here is a Screenshoot: https://prnt.sc/ml7qi1

Comment: Did you import the package? `import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';`

Comment: Yes i did, i imported the package, ty for say that i going to modify my question <3

Comment: I noticed you used `include`... maybe you have to use import how I did in my previous comment. Also I noticed you have an extra colon `:` in `include ':react-native-image-picker'` is that a type?

Comment: i put that code android/settings.gradle, because the documentation say

Comment: The documentation says to use `import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';` from https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "resolved" the problem just modify imagapicker code from React-Native to expo Image-Picker, if you wanna more information, here is the documentation https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by updating my import:

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';

ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
         // code here
};
```

It worked for me